# Como utilizar SCOPE_IDENTITY em sqlite

Tags: javascript, mysql, apache-cordova, sqlite

Tenho um aplicação mobile que insere um cadastro no BD e preciso que me retorne o ID deste cadastro, mas não sei como utilizar e nem sei se funciona o SCOPE_IDENTITY no sqlite, o meu código está assim:

```
var idSolicitacao = tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ouvidoria10 (assunto,mensagem,endereco,anexo,status, id_Departamento) 
                    VALUES ("' + document.getElementById("InputAssunto").value
                        + '","' + document.getElementById("InputMensagem").value
                        + '","' + document.getElementById("InputEndereco").value
                        + '","' + document.getElementById("ArquivosAnexados").value
                        + '","No Mobile",0);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()');
        alert(idSolicitacao);
```

Comment: É para usar com android?

Comment: com phonegap, no js

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por ordem de importância: nunca, nunca, **nunca** construa uma consulta SQL concatenando strings a menos que você saiba exatamente o que você está fazendo. Faça isso:

```
var idSolicitacao = tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ouvidoria10 (assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, "No Mobile", 0); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()', [
    document.getElementById("InputAssunto").value,
    document.getElementById("InputMensagem").value,
    document.getElementById("InputEndereco").value,
    document.getElementById("ArquivosAnexados").value,
]);
alert(idSolicitacao);
```

Eu nunca usei o PhoneGap, e a documentação me pareceu péssima, mas se eu entendi direito, o segundo parâmetro da função `executeSQL` é uma lista; os elementos dessa lista são usados para preencher os `?` na consulta em si, e o PhoneGap que se vira pra colocar aspas no que precisar colocar aspas.

---

Em segundo lugar, todo dialeto SQL que eu conheço usa apenas aspas simples pra demarcar strings. Você vai precisar ajeitar a sua consulta:

```
var idSolicitacao = tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ouvidoria10 (" +
    "assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) " + 
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 'No Mobile', 0); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", [
    document.getElementById("InputAssunto").value,
    document.getElementById("InputMensagem").value,
    document.getElementById("InputEndereco").value,
    document.getElementById("ArquivosAnexados").value,
]);
alert(idSolicitacao);
```

---

Em terceiro lugar, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` é uma função exclusiva do SQL Server, que não funciona no SQLite. Por outro lado, pela [documentação do PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_sqlresultset_sqlresultset.md.html), o `executeSQL` retorna um objeto com um atributo `insertId`, que é exatamente o ID que você quer.

```
var resultSet = tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ouvidoria10 (" +
    "assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) " + 
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 'No Mobile', 0)", [
    document.getElementById("InputAssunto").value,
    document.getElementById("InputMensagem").value,
    document.getElementById("InputEndereco").value,
    document.getElementById("ArquivosAnexados").value,
]);
var idSolicitacao = resultSet.insertId;
alert(idSolicitacao);
```

---

Em quarto lugar, eu recomendo você usar `console.log` no lugar de `alert` pra debugar seu código — você vai precisar abrir o console JavaScript (no Chrome ou Firefox, basta clicar com o botão direito em qualquer lugar da página e escolher “Inspecionar Elemento”; o console é uma das abas da nova janela que vai aparecer).

Uma pessoa que eu conheço (que não sou eu, nem trabalhou comigo, antes que você pergunte) colocou um `alert('fodeu!!')` no código, mas esqueceu de tirar, e botou o código em produção; ele só descobriu quando um usuário ligou pro suporte desesperado dizendo que o sistema estava falando que fodeu. :P

Além de não aparecer pro usuário e evitar esse tipo de incidente, quando você dá `console.log` de um objeto, tanto no Chrome quanto no Firefox, você pode clicar nele pra ver o tipo do objeto e as propriedades dele, o que é bem mais útil que o `[object BlaBlaBla]` que aparece quando você faz `alert()`.

```
var resultSet = tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ouvidoria10 (" +
    "assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) " + 
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 'No Mobile', 0)", [
    document.getElementById("InputAssunto").value,
    document.getElementById("InputMensagem").value,
    document.getElementById("InputEndereco").value,
    document.getElementById("ArquivosAnexados").value,
]);
var idSolicitacao = resultSet.insertId;
console.log(idSolicitacao);
```